# is there a way to split validation from logic when using jquery-validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm using Jquery Validation, but I suspect that the code doesn't match with the best practices of OOP.

In my page I'm using a button that calls a javascript.

Example using sendInfo function:

`<script src="../bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

`<button type="button" onclick="sendInfo('/rest/info','123');">Infos</button>`

But to validate the form, I need to use the call $('...myform...').validate

Here an example:

```js
function sendInfo(sUrl, sParams){

    $("form[name='infoForm']").validate({

      rules: {
      },
      messages: {
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
          url: sURL,
          data: sParams,
          success: function(response) {
          }
        });
      }

    });

}
```

Is there a way to split the logic for validations from the call to $.ajax() ?

I would like to put the codes in separate files, something like this:

**info-validations.js**

```js
function infoValidations(){
    $("form[name='infoForm']").validate({
      rules: {
      },
      messages: {
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
      }
    });
}
```

**info.js**

```js
function sendInfo(sUrl, sParams){
    $.ajax({
      url: sURL,
      data: sParams,
      success: function(response) {
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to keep them in the same file. But you can split them up to multiple functions. The ideal solution would be something like:

```
function handleFormSubmit(sUrl, sParams) {
  if (validateForm(sParams)) {
    sendRequest(sUrls, sParams);
  }
}

function validateForm(sParams) {}

function sendRequest(sUrl, sParams) {}
```

But it's not possible with the jQuery validate plugin, so I would propose the following (you have to adjust it to fit your needs, but I think you get the point).

```
function sendInfo(sParams){
  $("form[name='infoForm']").validate({
    rules: { },
    messages: { },
    submitHandler: sendRequest
  });
}

// Use the form data from the validator
function sendRequest(form) {
  $.ajax({
  /* 
  * You can keep the URL in a hidden field in the form instead, 
  * to get it more semantic correct (even though the action 
  * property in the form would be the correct)
  */

    url: form.sURL,
    data: form,
    success: handleSucces
  });
}

function handleSuccess(response) { }
```

Btw this is in no way OOP :-)